# Show a Message Box after a Thread in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, message

I am a new to .Net.Please Help Me.
I have a button and one label in my aspx page , i would like to display text in label and after few seconds i would like to show message box  on button click .
My code is -

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> 
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="MyThread" 
       onclick="btnClick_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and **Code File-**

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblFirst.Text = "Thread Start!";

        Thread threadObj = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myThreadMethod));
        threadObj.Start();
    }

    public void myThreadMethod()
    {
        //Server Code that take long time..
        Debug.Write("Thread Ending");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"msgbox","alert('End');",true);

    }
```

I got Label's Text Changing but Message Box was not shown.
Is it possible to show a Message Box ,after a thread?

How can I do this?
Thanks for your interests and replies.

Comment: You can use AJAX (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874.aspx) to accomplish this, or Client Callbacks -See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx for reading around this subject. There are lots of other frameworks you can use to accomplish this too. The key thing is that once the content is sent to the client, your server side events are effectively finished for that request which is why the above doesn't work. There's a fully worked example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210.aspx

Comment: I think that you be better of using JQUERY with a call back

Comment: Did you try callback method of thread?

Answer (score 1):

Use a backgroundworker, then add the event BackGroundWorker complete and in that event u add your messagebox

```
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

    // setup the anonymous event, this fires when the thread starts
    bgw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // do work here
    };

    // event when the thread has finished
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        // set yr messagebox here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nyein Nyein Chan Chan:

```
   Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Your message is here.')</script>");
```

Comment: By This,I got an Error-"Response is not available in this context."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);`
Replace x by time in milliseconds.
After this you can use `Button1.PerformClick();`
where Button1 is the name of the button.